# Appium screenshot is sometimes saved sideways, or upside down, regardless of physical device's orientation

Tags: python, opencv, appium, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

With my physical device in Landscape, the Appium screenshots are sometimes saved in Portrait, and sometimes in Landscape.  How do I go about controlling the saved image's orientation.

This is causing OpenCV's image comparison to fail.

I have found a handful of potential fixes online but none have worked.  The issue is best described [here](https://appiumpro.com/editions/112-how-to-specify-screenshot-orientation-for-ios-devices), but that solution using Python didn't work.

Potential fixes have included:

- `cv2.imread(checkpoint_filepath, cv2.IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL | cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)`
- configuring Appium's `screenshotOrientation` Setting (see link above)
- getting and setting Appium's `orientation`

All I want is for my physical device's orientation (landscape/portrait) to be reflected in the saved screenshot.

Comment: every time is the same screen or different screen you are trying to take screenshot?

Comment: @Mani my landscape screenshots are always saved as landscape images, but rotated counter-clockwise 90 degrees.

Comment: could you help with any screenshot how getting saved & what exactly you want ?